# understanding the flow of a simple dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I just started understanding the concept of dynamic programming. I understand it is used to cache results for future calls and its really efficient in designing complex algorithms that give an exponential runtime. What I don't understand is how the flow would work programmatically. For example to calculate the nth Fibonacci number using dynamic programming as follows. What is the flow like in the program?

```
int[] fibMap = new int[max]
int fibo(int i){
  if(i == 0) return 0;
  if(i == 1) return 1;
  if( fibMap[i] != 0) return fibMap[i]; // return cached result
  fibMap[i] = fibo(i-1)+fibo(i-2);      //Cache result
  return fibMap[i];
}
```

I found this code from one of the Java reference books that I am using but I am having hard time figuring out how this program would work. Say if we would want to calculate a simple fibo(3) or fibo(5), could someone please explain me how the program would cache result and how the overall flow would work for this problem compared to a normal recursive approach without DP like below?

```
int fibo(int i){
   if(i == 0) return 0;
   if( i == 1) return 1;
   return fibo(i-1) + fibo(i-2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking out the trusty old pencil and paper and following this by hand?

Comment: By the way, what you're doing is called memoization. It's basically the same thing as dynamic programming, except in the latter algorithms are typically written iteratively instead of recursively, which forces you to think about the flow and the data you keep track of explicitly. Also, I fixed your typo.

Comment: Yes I broke it down on a paper. What I don't get is when in the first if loop where it says fibMap[i] != 0 then return fibMap[i]. If say i = 5 then in the first turn fibMap[5] would have no value right because there is nothing stored in the array yet. How does it still proceed?

Comment: @JimZilla: Since the value isn't correct, it then tries to evaluate `fibo(i-1)` and `fibo(i-2)`, and when those are completed, it stores the value and also returns it. Does that help?

Comment: Off topic, but couldn't resist: the first two lines can be replaced by one line: `if (i < 2) return i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is

```
int fibo(int i){
  if(i == 0) return 0;
  if(i == 1) return 1;
  if( fibMap[i] != 0) return fibMap[i]; // return cached result
  fibMap[i] = fibo(i-1)+fibo(i-2);      //Cache result
  return fibMap[i];
}
```

or, equivalently

```
int fibo(int i){
  if(i == 0) return 0;
  if(i == 1) return 1;
  if( fibMap[i] == 0)
    fibMap[i] = fibo(i-1)+fibo(i-2);      //Cache result
  return fibMap[i];
}
```

so the "flow" is basically exactly the same thing as the non-cached version, except that you avoid recalculating results you've already computed.

Comment: Thank you sir. After breaking my head a little I somewhat get it. So say if we had to evaluate fibo(3). As fibMap[3] == 0 it will break down into fibMap[3] = fibo(2) + fibo(1). fibo(2) would now have a new result in fibMap[2] = fibo(1) + fibo(0) which returns a value of 1 back to fibMap[2]. 
Now fibMap[3] = fibMap[2] + fibo(1) which is equal to 1 + 1 = 2.

Is this correct? If so how does storing the result in array help? I know this is a silly question but are these cached results stored outside the function?

Comment: @JimZilla: Yes you're correct. If the value is found in the array, then `fibo` isn't called again. Since every call generates an additional 2 calls in most cases, you would get an exponential number of calls to `fibo` if you didn't save the result somewhere, so that's why it helps.

Comment: aah! get it now. Thanks a lot!